# Got error: NO FARES/RBD/CARRIER 146 after submit OTA_Airpice

Tags: sabre

when i call OTA_Airprice than got error:*NO FARES/RBD/CARRIER146

Demo request:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
        <OTA_AirPriceRQ xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.6.0">
          <OriginDestinationInformation xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
            <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2016-06-29T17:55" DepartureDateTime="2016-06-29T15:20" FlightNumber="1559" ResBookDesigCode="V">
              <DestinationLocation LocationCode="HKG" />
              <MarketingCarrier Code="UO" FlightNumber="1559" />
              <OriginLocation LocationCode="DAD" />
            </FlightSegment>
            <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2016-07-06T14:45" DepartureDateTime="2016-07-06T14:05" FlightNumber="1558" ResBookDesigCode="V">
              <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DAD" />
              <MarketingCarrier Code="UO" FlightNumber="1558" />
              <OriginLocation LocationCode="HKG" />
            </FlightSegment>
          </OriginDestinationInformation>
          <PriceRequestInformation xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
            <OptionalQualifiers>
              <FlightQualifiers>
                <VendorPrefs>
                  <Airline Code="UO" />
                </VendorPrefs>
              </FlightQualifiers>
              <PricingQualifiers CurrencyCode="VND">
                <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
              </PricingQualifiers>
            </OptionalQualifiers>
          </PriceRequestInformation>
        </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
```

Data Reponse:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
        <OTA_AirPriceRS xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.6.0">
            <ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
                <Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2016-05-21T11:30:38+07:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                <Message>*NO FARES/RBD/CARRIER146</Message>
                <ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</ShortText>
            </SystemSpecificResults>
                </Error>
        </ApplicationResults>
        </OTA_AirPriceRS>
```

Support team or Anyone else have any issues. tell my what reason to fix

thanks and best regards

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same issue but thanks to Sabre Support Team they help me to resolve the issue. I Used `<RedisplayReservation NumAttempts="2" WaitInterval="5000"/>` . and instead of calling action OTA_AirPriceRQ directly. I used EnhancedAirBookRQ to Book and Price Air segments.

Sample Request/Response.

```
<EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2" version="3.2.0" IgnoreOnError="false" HaltOnError="false">

      <OTA_AirBookRQ>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="UC" />
        <HaltOnStatus Code="LL" />
        <HaltOnStatus Code="UL" />
        <HaltOnStatus Code="UN" />
        <HaltOnStatus Code="NO" />
        <HaltOnStatus Code="HL" />
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
          <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2016-06-29T09:00:00" ArrivalDateTime="2016-06-29T11:10:00" FlightNumber="613" NumberInParty="3" ResBookDesigCode="T" Status="NN">
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DXB" />
            <MarketingAirline Code="EK" FlightNumber="613" />
            <OperatingAirline Code="EK" />
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="ISB" />
          </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <RedisplayReservation NumAttempts="2" WaitInterval="5000"/>
      </OTA_AirBookRQ>

      <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
        <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
          <OptionalQualifiers>
            <PricingQualifiers>
              <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="2" />
              <PassengerType Code="CNN" Quantity="1" />
              <PassengerType Code="INF" Quantity="1" />
            </PricingQualifiers>
          </OptionalQualifiers>
        </PriceRequestInformation>
      </OTA_AirPriceRQ>

    </EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```

Successful Response..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EnhancedAirBookRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2">
    <ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="Complete">
        <Success timeStamp="2016-06-06T21:44:52.085-05:00"/>
    </ApplicationResults>
    <OTA_AirBookRS>
        <OriginDestinationOption>
            <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="06-29T11:10" DepartureDateTime="06-29T09:00" FlightNumber="0613" NumberInParty="003" ResBookDesigCode="T" Status="NN" eTicket="true">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DXB"/>
                <MarketingAirline Code="EK" FlightNumber="0613"/>
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="ISB"/>
            </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationOption>
    </OTA_AirBookRS>
    <OTA_AirPriceRS>
        <PriceQuote>
            <MiscInformation>
                <BaggageInfo>
                    <SubCodeProperties MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1" RPH="1">
                        <AncillaryFeeGroupCode>BG</AncillaryFeeGroupCode>
                        <CommercialNameofBaggageItemType>FREE BAGGAGE ALLOWANCE</CommercialNameofBaggageItemType>
                        <EMD_Type>4</EMD_Type>
                        <ExtendedSubCodeKey>0DFAAEK</ExtendedSubCodeKey>
                    </SubCodeProperties>
                    <SubCodeProperties MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1" RPH="2">
                        <AncillaryFeeGroupCode>BG</AncillaryFeeGroupCode>
                        <AncillaryService SubGroupCode="CY">
                            <Text>CARRY ON HAND BAGGAGE</Text>
                        </AncillaryService>
                        <CommercialNameofBaggageItemType>CARRYON HAND BAGGAGE ALLOWANCE</CommercialNameofBaggageItemType>
                        <EMD_Type>4</EMD_Type>
                        <ExtendedSubCodeKey>0LNABEK</ExtendedSubCodeKey>
                        <RFIC>C</RFIC>
                    </SubCodeProperties>
                    <SubCodeProperties MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1" RPH="3">
                        <AncillaryFeeGroupCode>BG</AncillaryFeeGroupCode>
                        <AncillaryService SubGroupCode="CY">
                            <Text>CARRY ON HAND BAGGAGE</Text>
                        </AncillaryService>
                        <CommercialNameofBaggageItemType>CARRY5KG 11LBUPTO 45LI 115LCM</CommercialNameofBaggageItemType>
                        <DescriptionOne Code="05">
                            <Text>UP TO 11 POUNDS/5 KILOGRAMS</Text>
                        </DescriptionOne>
                        <DescriptionTwo Code="4U">
                            <Text>UP TO 45 LINEAR INCHES/115 LINEAR CENTIMETERS</Text>
                        </DescriptionTwo>
                        <EMD_Type>4</EMD_Type>
                        <ExtendedSubCodeKey>0MLACEK</ExtendedSubCodeKey>
                        <RFIC>C</RFIC>
                        <SizeWeightInfo>
                            <MaximumSizeInAlternate Units="C">115</MaximumSizeInAlternate>
                            <MaximumSize Units="I">45</MaximumSize>
                            <MaximumWeightInAlternate Units="K">5</MaximumWeightInAlternate>
                            <MaximumWeight Units="L">11</MaximumWeight>
                        </SizeWeightInfo>
                    </SubCodeProperties>
                </BaggageInfo>
                <HeaderInformation MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1">
                    <DepartureDate>2016-06-29</DepartureDate>
                    <LastTicketingDate>06-08T23:59</LastTicketingDate>
                    <Text>VALIDATING CARRIER - EK</Text>
                    <Text>BAG ALLOWANCE     -ISBDXB-30KG/EK</Text>
                    <Text>CARRY ON ALLOWANCE</Text>
                    <Text>ISBDXB-01P/EK</Text>
                    <Text>CARRY ON CHARGES</Text>
                    <Text>ISBDXB-EK-CARRY ON FEES UNKNOWN-CONTACT CARRIER</Text>
                    <Text>ADDITIONAL ALLOWANCES AND/OR DISCOUNTS MAY APPLY DEPENDING ON</Text>
                    <Text>FLYER-SPECIFIC FACTORS /E.G. FREQUENT FLYER STATUS/MILITARY/</Text>
                    <Text>CREDIT CARD FORM OF PAYMENT/EARLY PURCHASE OVER INTERNET,ETC./</Text>
                    <Text>EACH CNN REQUIRES ACCOMPANYING SAME CABIN ADT</Text>
                    <Text>VALIDATING CARRIER - EK</Text>
                    <Text>BAG ALLOWANCE     -ISBDXB-30KG/EK</Text>
                    <Text>CARRY ON ALLOWANCE</Text>
                    <Text>ISBDXB-01P/EK</Text>
                    <Text>CARRY ON CHARGES</Text>
                    <Text>ISBDXB-EK-CARRY ON FEES UNKNOWN-CONTACT CARRIER</Text>
                    <Text>ADDITIONAL ALLOWANCES AND/OR DISCOUNTS MAY APPLY DEPENDING ON</Text>
                    <Text>FLYER-SPECIFIC FACTORS /E.G. FREQUENT FLYER STATUS/MILITARY/</Text>
                    <Text>CREDIT CARD FORM OF PAYMENT/EARLY PURCHASE OVER INTERNET,ETC./</Text>
                    <Text>REQUIRES ACCOMPANYING ADT PASSENGER</Text>
                    <Text>EACH INF REQUIRES ACCOMPANYING ADT PASSENGER</Text>
                    <Text>VALIDATING CARRIER - EK</Text>
                    <Text>BAG ALLOWANCE     -ISBDXB-10KG/EK</Text>
                    <Text>CARRY ON ALLOWANCE</Text>
                    <Text>ISBDXB-01P/EK</Text>
                    <Text>01/UP TO 11 POUNDS/5 KILOGRAMS AND UP TO 45 LINEAR INCHES/</Text>
                    <Text>115 LINEAR CENTIMETERS</Text>
                    <Text>CARRY ON CHARGES</Text>
                    <Text>ISBDXB-EK-CARRY ON FEES UNKNOWN-CONTACT CARRIER</Text>
                    <Text>ADDITIONAL ALLOWANCES AND/OR DISCOUNTS MAY APPLY DEPENDING ON</Text>
                    <Text>FLYER-SPECIFIC FACTORS /E.G. FREQUENT FLYER STATUS/MILITARY/</Text>
                    <Text>CREDIT CARD FORM OF PAYMENT/EARLY PURCHASE OVER INTERNET,ETC./</Text>
                    <Text>29JUN DEPARTURE DATE ----- LAST DAY TO PURCHASE  8JUN</Text>
                    <ValidatingCarrier Code="EK"/>
                </HeaderInformation>
                <MultiTicketInformation MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1">
                    <CurrencyCode>PKR</CurrencyCode>
                    <TicketNumber>0</TicketNumber>
                    <TotalAmount>78139</TotalAmount>
                </MultiTicketInformation>
            </MiscInformation>
            <PricedItinerary CurrencyCode="PKR" MultiTicket="false" TotalAmount="78139">
                <AirItineraryPricingInfo MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1">
                    <BaggageProvisions RPH="1">
                        <Associations>
                            <CarrierCode RPH="1">EK</CarrierCode>
                            <CountForSegmentAssociatedID>1</CountForSegmentAssociatedID>
                            <DepartureDate RPH="1">2016-06-29</DepartureDate>
                            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DXB" RPH="1"/>
                            <FlightNumber RPH="1">613</FlightNumber>
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="ISB" RPH="1"/>
                            <PNR_Segment RPH="1">2</PNR_Segment>
                            <ResBookDesigCode RPH="1">T</ResBookDesigCode>
                            <StatusCode RPH="1">SS</StatusCode>
                        </Associations>
                        <CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>EK</CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>
                        <ProvisionType>A</ProvisionType>
                        <SubCodeInfo>
                            <SubCodeForChargesOthers>0DFAAEK</SubCodeForChargesOthers>
                        </SubCodeInfo>
                        <WeightLimit Units="K">30</WeightLimit>
                    </BaggageProvisions>
                    <BaggageProvisions RPH="2">
                        <Associations>
                            <CarrierCode RPH="1">EK</CarrierCode>
                            <CountForSegmentAssociatedID>1</CountForSegmentAssociatedID>
                            <DepartureDate RPH="1">2016-06-29</DepartureDate>
                            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DXB" RPH="1"/>
                            <FlightNumber RPH="1">613</FlightNumber>
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="ISB" RPH="1"/>
                            <PNR_Segment RPH="1">2</PNR_Segment>
                            <ResBookDesigCode RPH="1">T</ResBookDesigCode>
                            <StatusCode RPH="1">SS</StatusCode>
                        </Associations>
                        <CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>EK</CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>
                        <NumPiecesBDI>1</NumPiecesBDI>
                        <ProvisionType>B</ProvisionType>
                        <SubCodeInfo>
                            <SubCodeForChargesOthers>0LNABEK</SubCodeForChargesOthers>
                        </SubCodeInfo>
                    </BaggageProvisions>
                    <FareCalculation>
                        <Text>ISB EK DXB157.58NUC157.58END ROE104.706</Text>
                    </FareCalculation>
                    <FareCalculationBreakdown>
                        <Branch FirstJointCarrier="EK" PCC="DF08"/>
                        <Departure AirlineCode="EK" AirportCode="ISB" ArrivalAirportCode="DXB" ArrivalCityCode="DXB" CityCode="ISB" GenericInd="O"/>
                        <FareBasis Cabin="Y" Code="TOEAPPK1" FareAmount="157.58" FarePassengerType="ADT" FareType="P" FilingCarrier="EK" GlobalInd="EH" Market="ISBDXB" TripTypeInd="O"/>
                        <FreeBaggageAllowance>KG030</FreeBaggageAllowance>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>3</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>4</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>5</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>6</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>7</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>8</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>9</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>10</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>11</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>12</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>15</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>16</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>18</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                    </FareCalculationBreakdown>
                    <ItinTotalFare NonRefundableInd="N">
                        <BaggageInfo>
                            <NonUS_DOT_Disclosure>
                                <Text>BAG ALLOWANCE     -ISBDXB-30KG/EK</Text>
                                <Text>CARRY ON ALLOWANCE</Text>
                                <Text>ISBDXB-01P/EK</Text>
                                <Text>CARRY ON CHARGES</Text>
                                <Text>ISBDXB-EK-CARRY ON FEES UNKNOWN-CONTACT CARRIER</Text>
                                <Text>ADDITIONAL ALLOWANCES AND/OR DISCOUNTS MAY APPLY DEPENDING ON</Text>
                                <Text>FLYER-SPECIFIC FACTORS /E.G. FREQUENT FLYER STATUS/MILITARY/</Text>
                                <Text>CREDIT CARD FORM OF PAYMENT/EARLY PURCHASE OVER INTERNET,ETC./</Text>
                            </NonUS_DOT_Disclosure>
                        </BaggageInfo>
                        <BaseFare Amount="16500" CurrencyCode="PKR"/>
                        <Endorsements>
                            <Text>NON-END/SAVER/ONLY CHK-IN REWARD UPGRADE</Text>
                        </Endorsements>
                        <Taxes TotalAmount="8703">
                            <Tax Amount="1500" TaxCode="SP1" TaxName="EMBARKATION TAX" TicketingTaxCode="SP"/>
                            <Tax Amount="5000" TaxCode="RG" TaxName="FEDERAL EXCISE DUTY" TicketingTaxCode="RG"/>
                            <Tax Amount="1030" TaxCode="XZ" TaxName="SECURITY CHARGE" TicketingTaxCode="XZ"/>
                            <Tax Amount="1030" TaxCode="YD" TaxName="INFRASTRUCTURE DEVELOPMENT CHA" TicketingTaxCode="YD"/>
                            <Tax Amount="143" TaxCode="ZR" TaxName="INTL ADVANCED PSGR INFORMATION" TicketingTaxCode="ZR"/>
                        </Taxes>
                        <TotalFare Amount="25203" CurrencyCode="PKR"/>
                    </ItinTotalFare>
                    <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="2"/>
                    <PTC_FareBreakdown>
                        <Cabin>Y</Cabin>
                        <FareBasis Code="TOEAPPK1" FareAmount="157.58" FarePassengerType="ADT" FareType="P" FilingCarrier="EK" GlobalInd="EH" Market="ISBDXB"/>
                        <FreeBaggageAllowance>KG030</FreeBaggageAllowance>
                    </PTC_FareBreakdown>
                </AirItineraryPricingInfo>
                <AirItineraryPricingInfo MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1">
                    <BaggageProvisions RPH="1">
                        <Associations>
                            <CarrierCode RPH="1">EK</CarrierCode>
                            <CountForSegmentAssociatedID>1</CountForSegmentAssociatedID>
                            <DepartureDate RPH="1">2016-06-29</DepartureDate>
                            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DXB" RPH="1"/>
                            <FlightNumber RPH="1">613</FlightNumber>
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="ISB" RPH="1"/>
                            <PNR_Segment RPH="1">2</PNR_Segment>
                            <ResBookDesigCode RPH="1">T</ResBookDesigCode>
                            <StatusCode RPH="1">SS</StatusCode>
                        </Associations>
                        <CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>EK</CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>
                        <ProvisionType>A</ProvisionType>
                        <SubCodeInfo>
                            <SubCodeForChargesOthers>0DFAAEK</SubCodeForChargesOthers>
                        </SubCodeInfo>
                        <WeightLimit Units="K">30</WeightLimit>
                    </BaggageProvisions>
                    <BaggageProvisions RPH="2">
                        <Associations>
                            <CarrierCode RPH="1">EK</CarrierCode>
                            <CountForSegmentAssociatedID>1</CountForSegmentAssociatedID>
                            <DepartureDate RPH="1">2016-06-29</DepartureDate>
                            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DXB" RPH="1"/>
                            <FlightNumber RPH="1">613</FlightNumber>
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="ISB" RPH="1"/>
                            <PNR_Segment RPH="1">2</PNR_Segment>
                            <ResBookDesigCode RPH="1">T</ResBookDesigCode>
                            <StatusCode RPH="1">SS</StatusCode>
                        </Associations>
                        <CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>EK</CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>
                        <NumPiecesBDI>1</NumPiecesBDI>
                        <ProvisionType>B</ProvisionType>
                        <SubCodeInfo>
                            <SubCodeForChargesOthers>0LNABEK</SubCodeForChargesOthers>
                        </SubCodeInfo>
                    </BaggageProvisions>
                    <FareCalculation>
                        <Text>ISB EK DXB118.18NUC118.18END ROE104.706</Text>
                    </FareCalculation>
                    <FareCalculationBreakdown>
                        <Branch FirstJointCarrier="EK" PCC="DF08"/>
                        <Departure AirlineCode="EK" AirportCode="ISB" ArrivalAirportCode="DXB" ArrivalCityCode="DXB" CityCode="ISB" GenericInd="O"/>
                        <FareBasis Cabin="Y" Code="TOEAPPK1CH" FareAmount="118.18" FarePassengerType="CNN" FareType="P" FilingCarrier="EK" GlobalInd="EH" Market="ISBDXB" TripTypeInd="O"/>
                        <FreeBaggageAllowance>KG030</FreeBaggageAllowance>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>3</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>4</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>5</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>6</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>7</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>8</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>9</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>10</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>11</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>12</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>15</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>16</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>18</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>19</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                    </FareCalculationBreakdown>
                    <ItinTotalFare NonRefundableInd="N">
                        <BaggageInfo>
                            <NonUS_DOT_Disclosure>
                                <Text>BAG ALLOWANCE     -ISBDXB-30KG/EK</Text>
                                <Text>CARRY ON ALLOWANCE</Text>
                                <Text>ISBDXB-01P/EK</Text>
                                <Text>CARRY ON CHARGES</Text>
                                <Text>ISBDXB-EK-CARRY ON FEES UNKNOWN-CONTACT CARRIER</Text>
                                <Text>ADDITIONAL ALLOWANCES AND/OR DISCOUNTS MAY APPLY DEPENDING ON</Text>
                                <Text>FLYER-SPECIFIC FACTORS /E.G. FREQUENT FLYER STATUS/MILITARY/</Text>
                                <Text>CREDIT CARD FORM OF PAYMENT/EARLY PURCHASE OVER INTERNET,ETC./</Text>
                            </NonUS_DOT_Disclosure>
                        </BaggageInfo>
                        <BaseFare Amount="12380" CurrencyCode="PKR"/>
                        <Endorsements>
                            <Text>NON-END/SAVER/ONLY CHK-IN REWARD UPGRADE</Text>
                        </Endorsements>
                        <Taxes TotalAmount="8703">
                            <Tax Amount="1500" TaxCode="SP1" TaxName="EMBARKATION TAX" TicketingTaxCode="SP"/>
                            <Tax Amount="5000" TaxCode="RG" TaxName="FEDERAL EXCISE DUTY" TicketingTaxCode="RG"/>
                            <Tax Amount="1030" TaxCode="XZ" TaxName="SECURITY CHARGE" TicketingTaxCode="XZ"/>
                            <Tax Amount="1030" TaxCode="YD" TaxName="INFRASTRUCTURE DEVELOPMENT CHA" TicketingTaxCode="YD"/>
                            <Tax Amount="143" TaxCode="ZR" TaxName="INTL ADVANCED PSGR INFORMATION" TicketingTaxCode="ZR"/>
                        </Taxes>
                        <TotalFare Amount="21083" CurrencyCode="PKR"/>
                    </ItinTotalFare>
                    <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="CNN" Quantity="1"/>
                    <PTC_FareBreakdown>
                        <Cabin>Y</Cabin>
                        <FareBasis Code="TOEAPPK1CH" FareAmount="118.18" FarePassengerType="CNN" FareType="P" FilingCarrier="EK" GlobalInd="EH" Market="ISBDXB"/>
                        <FreeBaggageAllowance>KG030</FreeBaggageAllowance>
                    </PTC_FareBreakdown>
                </AirItineraryPricingInfo>
                <AirItineraryPricingInfo MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1">
                    <BaggageProvisions RPH="1">
                        <Associations>
                            <CarrierCode RPH="1">EK</CarrierCode>
                            <CountForSegmentAssociatedID>1</CountForSegmentAssociatedID>
                            <DepartureDate RPH="1">2016-06-29</DepartureDate>
                            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DXB" RPH="1"/>
                            <FlightNumber RPH="1">613</FlightNumber>
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="ISB" RPH="1"/>
                            <PNR_Segment RPH="1">2</PNR_Segment>
                            <ResBookDesigCode RPH="1">T</ResBookDesigCode>
                            <StatusCode RPH="1">SS</StatusCode>
                        </Associations>
                        <CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>EK</CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>
                        <ProvisionType>A</ProvisionType>
                        <SubCodeInfo>
                            <SubCodeForChargesOthers>0DFAAEK</SubCodeForChargesOthers>
                        </SubCodeInfo>
                        <WeightLimit Units="K">10</WeightLimit>
                    </BaggageProvisions>
                    <BaggageProvisions RPH="2">
                        <Associations>
                            <CarrierCode RPH="1">EK</CarrierCode>
                            <CountForSegmentAssociatedID>1</CountForSegmentAssociatedID>
                            <DepartureDate RPH="1">2016-06-29</DepartureDate>
                            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DXB" RPH="1"/>
                            <FlightNumber RPH="1">613</FlightNumber>
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="ISB" RPH="1"/>
                            <PNR_Segment RPH="1">2</PNR_Segment>
                            <ResBookDesigCode RPH="1">T</ResBookDesigCode>
                            <StatusCode RPH="1">SS</StatusCode>
                        </Associations>
                        <CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>EK</CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>
                        <NumPiecesBDI>1</NumPiecesBDI>
                        <NumPiecesITR>1</NumPiecesITR>
                        <ProvisionType>B</ProvisionType>
                        <SubCodeInfo>
                            <SubCodeForAllowance RPH="1">0MLACEK</SubCodeForAllowance>
                            <SubCodeForChargesOthers>0LNABEK</SubCodeForChargesOthers>
                        </SubCodeInfo>
                    </BaggageProvisions>
                    <FareCalculation>
                        <Text>ISB EK DXB15.75NUC15.75END ROE104.706</Text>
                    </FareCalculation>
                    <FareCalculationBreakdown>
                        <Branch FirstJointCarrier="EK" PCC="DF08"/>
                        <Departure AirlineCode="EK" AirportCode="ISB" ArrivalAirportCode="DXB" ArrivalCityCode="DXB" CityCode="ISB" GenericInd="O"/>
                        <FareBasis Cabin="Y" Code="TOEAPPK1IN" FareAmount="15.75" FarePassengerType="INF" FareType="P" FilingCarrier="EK" GlobalInd="EH" Market="ISBDXB" TripTypeInd="O"/>
                        <FreeBaggageAllowance>KG010</FreeBaggageAllowance>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>3</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>4</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>5</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>6</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>7</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>8</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>9</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>10</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>11</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>12</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>15</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>16</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>18</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>19</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                    </FareCalculationBreakdown>
                    <ItinTotalFare NonRefundableInd="N">
                        <BaggageInfo>
                            <NonUS_DOT_Disclosure>
                                <Text>BAG ALLOWANCE     -ISBDXB-10KG/EK</Text>
                                <Text>CARRY ON ALLOWANCE</Text>
                                <Text>ISBDXB-01P/EK</Text>
                                <Text>01/UP TO 11 POUNDS/5 KILOGRAMS AND UP TO 45 LINEAR INCHES/</Text>
                                <Text>115 LINEAR CENTIMETERS</Text>
                                <Text>CARRY ON CHARGES</Text>
                                <Text>ISBDXB-EK-CARRY ON FEES UNKNOWN-CONTACT CARRIER</Text>
                                <Text>ADDITIONAL ALLOWANCES AND/OR DISCOUNTS MAY APPLY DEPENDING ON</Text>
                                <Text>FLYER-SPECIFIC FACTORS /E.G. FREQUENT FLYER STATUS/MILITARY/</Text>
                                <Text>CREDIT CARD FORM OF PAYMENT/EARLY PURCHASE OVER INTERNET,ETC./</Text>
                            </NonUS_DOT_Disclosure>
                        </BaggageInfo>
                        <BaseFare Amount="1650" CurrencyCode="PKR"/>
                        <Endorsements>
                            <Text>NON-END/SAVER/ONLY CHK-IN REWARD UPGRADE</Text>
                        </Endorsements>
                        <Taxes TotalAmount="5000">
                            <Tax Amount="5000" TaxCode="RG" TaxName="FEDERAL EXCISE DUTY" TicketingTaxCode="RG"/>
                        </Taxes>
                        <TotalFare Amount="6650" CurrencyCode="PKR"/>
                    </ItinTotalFare>
                    <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="INF" Quantity="1"/>
                    <PTC_FareBreakdown>
                        <Cabin>Y</Cabin>
                        <FareBasis Code="TOEAPPK1IN" FareAmount="15.75" FarePassengerType="INF" FareType="P" FilingCarrier="EK" GlobalInd="EH" Market="ISBDXB"/>
                        <FreeBaggageAllowance>KG010</FreeBaggageAllowance>
                    </PTC_FareBreakdown>
                </AirItineraryPricingInfo>
            </PricedItinerary>
        </PriceQuote>
    </OTA_AirPriceRS>
</EnhancedAirBookRS>
```

Comment: Great Thanks. I am amazed why you did not get so many votes by this awesome answer. Keep up the good work man.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting those flights as available from a shopping service?
E.g.: from https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max

'RBD' in the error refers to the ResBookDesigCode="V" you are submitting in the request for each flight.

Comment: I think not sure, because sometimes i still got book ticket success.